# Django rest framework , serializer - after submitting with POST method will not lead back to homepage

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am a django newbie here. I am confused as in why after i have submitted a POST request, the django rest framework will lead me to this page here

[image]

instead of bringing me back to my homepage

this is my 
views.py:

```
class TableData(APIView):
  def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    startRange = request.POST.get('mcap')
    endRange = int(startRange) + 29868
    sector = request.POST['cat']
    print(str(sector))
    stocks =  StockInfo.objects.filter(Q(company__company_categories__contains=sector),Q(companymcap__range=(startRange,endRange)),Q(datetimecollect__contains=datetime.date(2018,3,13)))
    serializer = TableSerializer(stocks,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

my serializers.py:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    #stocks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    company_name = serializers.CharField(source='company.company_name')
    company_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='company.company_id')
    company_categories = serializers.CharField(source='company.company_categories')
    class Meta:
        model = StockInfo
        fields = ('company_name', 'company_id', 'company_categories','companyprice', 'companyvolume', 'companyeps', 'companydps', 'companynta', 'companype', 'companydy', 'companyroe', 'companyptbv', 'companymcap')
```

My initial idea is that after a person has chosen some criteria from my html form then when they submit the form, I will query the database based on their criteria and load it into a serializer. Then using the serializer to fill up my ajax data table in my html page.

I tried my best and i still do not know what is wrong...

**EDITED**

lets say if i were to use together with the ajax datatable... do i still do it the same way like how i redirect my this page? 
below in the snippet of the ajax data table in my mypage.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                                        var table = $('#datatable').dataTable( {
                                             "processing": true,
                                             "searching": false,
                                             "ajax": {
                                                 "processing": true,
                                                 "url": "{% url 'tableData' %}",
                                                 "dataSrc": ""
                                             },

                                             "columns": [
                                                     { "data": "company_name" },
                                                     { "data": "company_id" },
                                                     { "data": "companyprice" },
                                                     { "data": "companyvolume" },
                                                     { "data": "companyeps" },
                                                     { "data": "companydps" },
                                                     { "data": "companynta" },
                                                     { "data": "companype" },
                                                     { "data": "companydy" },
                                                     { "data": "companyroe" },
                                                     { "data": "companyptbv" },
                                                     { "data": "companymcap" }
                                                 ]
                                         } );
                                     } );
```

the url: {% url 'tableData'%} will lead to the url /api/table/data.

**EDITED AGAIN**

this is my html template

```
         <!-- Page Content Holder -->
{% extends "app/header.html" %}
{%load rest_framework%}
{% block nav_home%}
class="active"
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
        <div id="content">              
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container" style="display: inline;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav px-3 ml-auto" style="display:inline-block;">
                            <li class="nav-item text-nowrap d-flex flex-row">
                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"><a href="{% url 'register' %}"> Sign Out</a></i>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="col-xl-10">
                            <form action="{% url 'stock' %}" method='GET'>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control border-secondary py-2" type="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" name="q" placeholder="Search ticker">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xl-10">
                <div class="card" style="width: 1070px;">
                  <div class="card-body">

                    <h5 class="card-title">Uptrend Prediction</h5>
                    <br>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-outline-info waves-effect" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Categories
                      </button>

                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Most Active</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Least Active</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Top Gainers</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Top Losers</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <form action="{% url 'tableData' %}" method="POST"><!--start of formquery-->
                        <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                            <h2 style="font: 16px Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin: 0.5em;">Market Cap:</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group" style="font: 16px Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                                    <input type="radio" id="mcap" href="#" name="mcap" value="29868" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">Small Cap</input>
                                    <input type="radio" id="mcap" href="#" name="mcap" value="59736" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">Mid Cap</input>
                                    <input type="radio" id="mcap" href="#" name="mcap" value="89604" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">Large Cap</input>
                                    <input type="radio" id="mcap" href="#" name="mcap" value="119472" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">Mega Cap</input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                              <h2 style="font: 16px Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin: 0.5em;">   Sectors:   </h2>
                            </div>
                            <!--change the dropdown from bootstrap to normal select options-->
                            <!-- removed healthcare from the option-->
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <select name="cat">
                                        <option name="cat" value="Basic"> Basic Materials </option>
                                        <option name="cat" value="Consumer"> Consumer Goods </option>
                                        <option name="cat" value="Serv"> Services </option>
                                        <option name="cat" value="Technology"> Technology </option>
                                        <option name="cat" value="Finance"> Financial </option>
                                        <option name="cat" value="Hotels"> Hotels </option>
                                        <option name="cat" value="Ind"> Industrial Goods </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                              <h2 style="font: 16px Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin: 0.5em;">Share price: </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                  <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-outline-info waves-effect" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    All
                                  </button>

                                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Up To RM1</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Above RM1</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                              <h2 style="font: 16px Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin: 0.5em;">P/E: </h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-outline-info waves-effect" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    All
                                    </button>

                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Below 10</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10-15</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">16-25</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Above 25</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-2" >
                              <h2 style="font: 16px Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin: 0.5em;">P/B Value: </h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-outline-info waves-effect" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    All
                                    </button>

                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Up to 0.5</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Up to 1.0</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Up to 2.0</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Above 2.0</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">
                                        Filter Stocks
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form><!-- end of formquery-->
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="container">

                                <table id="datatable" class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Volume</th>
                                        <th>EPS</th>
                                        <th>DPS</th>
                                        <th>NTA</th>
                                        <th>PE</th>
                                        <th>DY</th>
                                        <th>ROE</th>
                                        <th>PTBV</th>
                                        <th>M.Cap</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {% for v in data%}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{v.company_name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                    <tr>

                                    </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>


                                <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#datatable').DataTable({ data: "{{data}}" });;
                                     } );






                                </script>               

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>      


        </div>



{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE:SOLVED**

in my datatable in my html i did this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                                        var json = JSON.stringify({{data | safe}});
                                        $('#datatable').DataTable({ 
                                            "data": JSON.parse(json), 
                                             "columns": [
                                                     { "data": "company_name" },
                                                     { "data": "company_id" },
                                                     {"data": "company_categories"},
                                                     { "data": "companyprice" },
                                                     { "data": "companyvolume" },
                                                     { "data": "companyeps" },
                                                     { "data": "companydps" },
                                                     { "data": "companynta" },
                                                     { "data": "companype" },
                                                     { "data": "companydy" },
                                                     { "data": "companyroe" },
                                                     { "data": "companyptbv" },
                                                     { "data": "companymcap" }
                                                 ]
                                        });;
                                     } );
```

in my views.py i did this

views.py

```
stocks =  StockInfo.objects.filter(Q(company__company_categories__contains=sector),Q(companyprice__range=(startPriceRange,endPriceRange)),Q(companymcap__range=(startRange,endRange)),Q(datetimecollect__contains=datetime.date(2018,3,13)))
    serializer = TableSerializer(stocks,many=True)
    #qs = serializers.serialize('json',stocks)
    testing = json.dumps(list(serializer.data))
    context = {'data':testing,}
return render(request,'mypage.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify any `template_name` in your view and you subclass `APIView`, so it's normal to take you to that page (image).

Use django `render` function with your homepage template or drf `HTMLRenderer`:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
class TableData(APIView):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        startRange = request.POST.get('mcap')
        endRange = int(startRange) + 29868
        sector = request.POST['cat']
        print(str(sector))
        ...
        serializer = TableSerializer(stocks,many=True)
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
        template_name = 'homepage.html'
        return Response({'data': serializer.data})
```

`data` is the variable you use in your homepage template to make use of `serializer.data`.

Comment: ah okay so lets say if i were to use this together with ajax datatable? will it be the same ? i will edit a snippet of that ajax datatable on my question... sry if i asked too many questions

Comment: In your Datatable snippet you use ajax and that makes another ajax query to your backend which is not needed as we already have data in your view class sent to your template called data. So use datatable Data $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data
} );

Comment: sorry @Yusef BH i tried $('#datatable').DataTable({ data:data }); but nothing is displayed out on the datatable. I have checked that my serializer.data has return some results

Comment: Ahh yeah, it's a template variable so try it like this $('#datatable').DataTable({ data: "{{data}}" });

Comment: i dont know if i am doing something wrong... but it still doesnt have any display though..

Comment: I think you should post your template, otherwise i have no clue :(

Comment: if you are referring to my html template...i am editing my html template in now...sry for all the troubles

Comment: Delete the `tbody` tag and it's content, there is no need for it. DataTables gonna take care of that.

Comment: i tried deleted that before but the datatables did not load any data thats why i am a bit confused XD

Comment: `tbody` there is no need for it, and i guess you should add `columns` option to your `Datatable`

Comment: oh yea man i added that and some arguments when passing into the datatable....thx for your help man ^_^ i will edit in my code

Comment: Ah ok. That's good. Please consider marking this answer as correct. Happy coding ;)